# Using a CASE inside an IN to give a possibility of multiple int's

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get a `CASE` statement working inside an `IN` statement where the first 2 conditions will result in 1 possible outcome, while the third will result in 2 possible outcomes. Which is why I'm using `CASE`. Here's the SQL that I have so far:

```
DECLARE @startDate date, @endDate date
DECLARE @AptTpye varchar(1)
SET @startDate = '2/17/2020'
SET @endDate = '2/18/2020'
-- 1 = Receiving : 2 = Shipping : 3 = Both
SET @AptTpye = 1

SELECT SAR.AppointmentID, SAR.LoadID, SAR2.DateValue [Check In], SAR3.EnteredOn [Scale In], SAR.LoadID + '*,', SAR.AppointmentType
FROM dbo.SAR_AppointmentMaster AS SAR
LEFT JOIN dbo.SAR_AppointmentTimes AS SAR2 ON SAR2.AppointmentID = SAR.AppointmentID AND SAR2.DateType = 'CHECKIN'
LEFT JOIN dbo.SAR_AppointmentWeights AS SAR3 ON SAR3.AppointmentID = SAR.AppointmentID AND SAR3.WeightType = 'SCALEIN'
WHERE SAR2.DateValue BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
    AND SAR.AppointmentType IN(CASE @AptTpye 
                                    WHEN '1' THEN 1 
                                    WHEN '2' THEN 2 
                                    WHEN '3' THEN (1, 2) 
                                END)
```

**Am I going about this wrong? Or is there a way to get this to work?**

I have also tried this:

```
SELECT SAR.AppointmentID, SAR.LoadID, SAR2.DateValue [Check In], SAR3.EnteredOn [Scale In], SAR.LoadID + '*,', SAR.AppointmentType
FROM dbo.SAR_AppointmentMaster AS SAR
LEFT JOIN dbo.SAR_AppointmentTimes AS SAR2 ON SAR2.AppointmentID = SAR.AppointmentID AND SAR2.DateType = 'CHECKIN'
LEFT JOIN dbo.SAR_AppointmentWeights AS SAR3 ON SAR3.AppointmentID = SAR.AppointmentID AND SAR3.WeightType = 'SCALEIN'
WHERE SAR2.DateValue BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
    AND (CASE @AptTpye 
                                    WHEN '1' THEN SAR.AppointmentType = 1 
                                    WHEN '2' THEN SAR.AppointmentType = 2 
                                    WHEN '3' THEN SAR.AppointmentType IN(1, 2) 
                                END)
```

Neither version works. The first version errors on the `WHEN '3' THEN` line and the second errors on the first `WHEN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want this logic:

```
(SAR.AppointmentType = @AptType OR
 @AptType = 3 AND SAR.AppointmentType IN (1, 2)
)
```

I see no reason for `@AptType` to be a string.

Note:  If you have only two appointment types, then this does the same thing:

```
(SAR.AppointmentType = @AptType OR
 @AptType = 3 
)
```

Comment: Crap! I'm an idiot! That works perfectly. I could even add more types and it would still work. Thanks!